# I need User input for my 2 doubles, but there's an Initialization error, but I don't want a set number for the doubles (Java)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double hourlyPR ;
        double hoursWorked ;
        double grossPay;
        grossPay = hourlyPR * hoursWorked ;

        float Withtax = (float) 0.1;
        float bigTax = (float) 0.12;
        float biggerTax = (float) 0.15;
        float giantTax = (float) 0.2;

        double bigNetpay = (grossPay - grossPay * bigTax);
        double biggerNetpay = (grossPay - grossPay * biggerTax);
        double giantNetpay = (grossPay - grossPay * giantTax);
        double netPay = (grossPay - grossPay * Withtax);

        System.out.println("Enter The Amount of Hours You've Worked:");
        hourlyPR = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter The Amount You've Earned:");
        hoursWorked= scan.nextDouble();



            if (grossPay <= 300.00) {

                System.out.println("With $" + hourlyPR + " per hour & " + hoursWorked + " hours worked...");
                System.out.println("You make: $" + grossPay + " before taxes, " + "and $" + netPay + " after taxes.");
            } else if (grossPay >= 300.01 && grossPay <= 400) {
                System.out.println("With $" + hourlyPR + " per hour & " + hoursWorked + " hours worked...");
                System.out.println("You make: $" + grossPay + " before taxes, " + "and $" + bigNetpay + " after taxes.");

            } else if (grossPay >= 400.1 && grossPay <= 500) {
                System.out.println("With $" + hourlyPR + " per hour & " + hoursWorked + " hours worked...");
                System.out.println("You make: $" + grossPay + " before taxes, " + "and $" + biggerNetpay + " after taxes.");
            } else if (grossPay >= 500.1);
        System.out.println("With $" + hourlyPR + " per hour & " + hoursWorked + " hours worked...");
        System.out.println("You make: $" + grossPay + " before taxes, " + "and $" + giantNetpay + " after taxes.");

    }
}
```

I need the hoursworked and hourlypay doubles to be user input, not intialized. EVerything seems to be fine but the fact that I cannot get user input for those two doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is at least one problem. Move scan calls to the top before you try to use them.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter The Amount of Hours You've Worked:");
double hourlyPR = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter The Amount You've Earned:");
double hoursWorked= scan.nextDouble();


double grossPay = hourlyPR * hoursWorked ;
```